# Constraint Layout not working in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to place 2 components next to each other such that the 1st component is on left side of screen and the 2nd is on right side with some margins.

To make sure, smaller screen sizes don't mess up I am using constraints so that they don't overlap each other.

However, the constraints dont seem to be working, not sure why. The 2nd component just goes off the screen for smaller screens. It doesnt follow the right margin of 10dp.

Similar constraints are working for me on another screen.

The code for the same is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/lightBlueColor">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/SensSpecCalcScreen_Lbl2"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectborder"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/DefaultValue_40.0"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I dont wanna use relative or linear layouts, trying to achieve this with constraint layout itself.

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:layout_width="60dp"` for EditText to 0?
i.e. `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="texttexttexttxetxtxtxtxt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/capture"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Whats the issue with the indentation? Its seems to work now apparently. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by indentation? Do you mean the marginStart of 250dp for the editText that I removed?

Comment: Nope, i didnt even notice that. I meant about moving constraintlayout tag (inside scrollview tag) to the start of the line. Because if you notice, the components like textview and edittext are indented to show that they are within that particular layout.

Comment: I had put that 250dp purposefully. Removing that was not the solution but instead moving the constraintlayout tag to the start of the line and removing the scrollview tag fixed the issue.
However, I have similar code in another screen, with scrollview and constraintlayout tag(at start of line) and that screen works fine.

Comment: Mainly the changes I made: app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/editText" in order for the textView to stop when it reaches the EditText and android:layout_width="0dp" in order for the textView to always spread inside the whole space before reaching the editText which have a fixed space.

Comment: I know that removing the 250dp was not the solution, I removed that just for the text of the TextView to fill the empty space in between and make the UI look nicer in case you have more than one line of text inside it.

Comment: What else do you have inside your layout beside this constraint layout?

Comment: A bunch of textviews, edittexts, seekbars and 1 button.

Comment: So your problem is solved by making the constraint layout your parent instead of the scrollView?

Comment: Correct, adding scrollview is messing it up somehow.

Comment: What if you placed the scrollView as a child inside constraintLayout, does it change anything?

Comment: Nope, still doesnt work. Since, scrollview can have only 1 child i have to wrap all my other components again under another constraint layout.

Comment: What if you remove the marginBottom of the scrollView, does it make any difference?

Comment: Try also to change layout_height of constraint layout to match_parent instead of wrap_content.

Comment: I made it to wrap_content because the android studio editor suggests me to do that by giving a warning.

Comment: That margin bottom is just to accommodate the bottom navigation bar.